# How to write integers to a file

Tags: python

I need to write

```
ranks[a], ranks[b], count
```

to a file, each time on a new line

I am using:

```
file = open("matrix.txt", "w")
for (a, b), count in counts.iteritems():
    file.write(ranks[a], ranks[b], count)

file.close()
```

but this is not working and returns

```
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Comment: Your output is being interpreted as 3 arguments to the write function, which as shown in your error, can only accept 1 argument.  You would want to concatenate the arguments into one variable and then pass that variable to the write function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the error says, [`file.write`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) only takes one arg. Try:

```
file.write("%s %s %s" % (ranks[a], ranks[b], count))
```

Comment: More likely `%d`. And don't forget `'\n'` too.

Comment: here `file.write("%d %d %d\n" % (ranks[a], ranks[b], count))`

Comment: @Julia - Add it to the first portion: "%s %s %s \n"

Comment: @Julia - "%s" % some_int will just call str() on it anyway, they're equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Hamish's answer is correct. But when you would be reading the contents back you would be reading them as `strings` and not as `integers`. So if you'd want to read them back as integers or as any other dataType, then I would suggest using some kind of `object serialization` like `pickle`.
 For `pickle`-ing your data, you should read [this page](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) in the official documentation. For your convenience, I am pasting a snippet from [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle):

```
# Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
import pickle
favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
```

```
# Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.
import pickle
favorite_color = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
# favorite_color is now { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want a variation on the `print` statement.

Python 2.x:

```
print >> file, ranks[a], ranks[b], count
```

Python 3.x:

```
print(ranks[a], ranks[b], count, file=file)
```

The advantage of the `print` statement over the `file.write` solution proposed above is that you don't have to worry about those pesky newlines.