# Writing Integers to a File

Tags: python, file-io, integer

I'm having a really difficult time writing integers out to a file. Here's my situation. I have a file, let's call it 'idlist.txt'. It has multiple columns and is fairly long (10,000 rows), but I only care about the first column of data.

I'm loading it into python using:

```
import numpy as np
FH = np.loadtxt('idlist.txt',delimiter=',',comments='#')

# Testing initial data type
print FH[0,0],type(FH[0,0])
>>> 85000370342.0 <type 'numpy.float64'>

# Converting to integers
F = [int(FH[i,0]) for i in range(len(FH))]
print F[0],type(F[0])
>>> 85000370342 <type 'long'>
```

As you can see, the data must be made into integers. What I now would like to do is to write the entries of this list out as the first column of another file (really the only column in the entire file), we can rename it 'idonly.txt'. Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
with open('idonly.txt','a') as f:
    for i in range(len(F)):
        f.write('%d\n' % (F[i]))
```

This is clearly not producing the desired output - when I open the file 'idonly.txt', each entry is actually a float (i.e. - 85000370342.0). What exactly is going on here, and why is writing integers to a file such a complicated task? I found the string formatting idea from here: [How to write integers to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932488/how-to-write-integers-to-a-file) , but it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: I'm even printing the value and type of F[i] at each step in my loops and it gives me the correct integer every time. I'm really confused how and when inside the code above each integer is changed into a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, well it appears that this is completely my fault. When I'm opening the file I'm using the mode 'a', which means append. It turns out that the first time I wrote this out to a file I did it incorrectly, and ever since I've been appending the correct answer onto that and simply not looking down as far as I should since it's a really long file.

For reference here are all of the modes you can use when handling files in python: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm. Choose carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
f.write('{}'.format(F[i]));
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, its just a different way to write the string formatter.